# Capistrano task git clone private gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I am attempting to write a Capistrano task that will 'deploy' a private gem I wrote to accompany a Rails project.

In `config/deploy.rb`

```
after :updating, :retrieve_my_gem
```

The file `lib/capistrano/tasks/retrieve_my_gem.rake` contains...

```
desc 'Clones my_gem from Github to vendor/git'
task :retrieve_my_gem do
  on roles(:app), in: :sequence do
    # Create the directory that will contain my gem
    gem_container_path = release_path.join('vendor/git')
    debug "Gem container path: #{gem_container_path}"
    if test "[ ! -d #{gem_container_path} ]"
      info "Creating local gem directory"
      execute 'mkdir', '-p', gem_container_path
    end

    gem_path = release_path.join('vendor/git/my_gem')
    debug "Gem path: #{gem_path}"
    if test "[ ! -d #{gem_path} ]"
      within gem_container_path do
        info "Cloning my gem to #{gem_path}"
        execute 'git clone git@github.com:username/my_gem.git', gem_path
      end
    else
      within gem_path do
        info "Updating my gem in #{gem_path}"
        execute 'git pull'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And `Gemfile` has...

```
gem 'my_gem', :path => 'vendor/git/my_gem/'
```

When I run my deploy task, the `gem_container_path` is created but it clones the repo `my_gem` into ~/my_gem instead of into `gem_container_path`. The deploy task continues and fails when attempt `bundle install` due to not finding 'my_gem' in 'vendor/git/my_gem/' as indicated in the Gemfile.

I am expecting the task to clone the repo to /var/www/project/releases/*/vendor/git/my_gem where * is replaced with the DateTime stamp that Capistrano generates for *this* release.

Why is Capistrano cloning the repo to my remote user's home directory and not to the specified path?

Comment: Just out of curiosity? what can you show the debug output of `gem_path`? (FYI. you have that `debug` line wrong. `debug "Gem path: #{gem_container_path}"`)

Comment: @PeteyT gem_path is `/var/www/project/releases/20150112224830/vendor/git/my_gem`

Comment: whats up with the `git@github.username/my_gem.git`; shouldn't that read `git@github.com:username/my_gem.git`? Just trying to weed out typo's here.

Comment: @PeteyT And thanks for pointing out the debug line!

Comment: @PeteyT RE: The Git URL that is a typo and I've corrected it now. The typo does not exist in the task because it successfully clones the repo to ~/my_gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was my execute statement:

```
execute 'git clone git@github.com:username/my_gem.git', gem_path
```

I changed it to

```
execute "git clone git@github.com:username/my_gem.git #{gem_path}"
```

and it is working as expected now.